# How to fix laravel 500 error on sitegound

Tags: laravel

I uploaded my laravel app on siteground shared hosting. When I visit the root index page it shows the page without errors but when I try to visit any other route it shows a 500 Internal Server Error. The error logs are empty.

What can be the cause of this problem ?I have also set all folders permission to 755

Comment: 500 is not an application error, so you won't find anything in the laravel log files. You will have to read the server log files in order to know how to fix it.

Comment: Did you try adding `public/` to the start of the routes?

Comment: I don't see anything in the server log files as well

Comment: Yes I added `public/` to the start of routes but it did not work

Comment: It works if I use link like this
`domain/index.php/login`

Comment: Please have a look in this article - https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-deployment-gives-500-internal-server-error

Comment: Already tried what is suggested in the link but it does not work

Answer (score 0):

you should enable rewrite_module in your php config